# Native library not loading under Android 4.0.3 (MIUI ROM)

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, abi

A customer contacted me - an Android app of mine broke once he updated his Android ROM to MIUI equivalent to Android 4.0.3. The relevant line in LogCat is:

```
04-09 10:37:09.326 17789 17789 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mylib: findLibrary returned null
```

The app, needless to say, worked before the upgrade. So the native library did not go magically missing. Any ideas why would Android 4.0.3 refuse to load a native library where earlier versions would? The library is built for x86 and for `armeabi` (not for `armeabi-v7a` though). The crash report contains the following lines:

```
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
```

So `armeabi` should be supported, right?

Possibly relevant info: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/N8FLjvM81pg/2rYeClQZcckJ). But the situation in the bug is the inverse of what I've got here.

Comment: I believe that the libloader bug is relevant here in some weird way. You should be able to reproduce the problem on emulator, and get a chance to analyse install log and what is written into the lib directory.

Comment: I've added armeabi-v7a to the build since :)