# Some users of my Android app are experiencing an Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

why is it that only some of my customers are experiencing an unsatisfied link error whilst it works flawlessly in most cases?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load Foo: findLibrary returned null
```

I read about this problem before but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# disable thumb mode
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE := Foo

#-Wno-psabi to remove warning about GCC 4.4 va_list warning
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK -Wno-psabi -Wno-write-strings

LOCAL_DEFAULT_CPP_EXTENSION := cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    source1.cpp \
    source2.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3):

One reason could be that you built the library for ARM v7 (i.e. with `APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a`) but not for ARM v6 (`APP_ABI=armeabi`). But maybe some of your customers are using MIPS, or x86 - powered devices?

If these explanations do not fit, please provide more info, e.g. show your `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files.

Comment: Ok, I added the makefile to my post.

Comment: Your Android.mk builds for `arm` only. Are you sure the complaints don't come from MIPS devices (quite popular in China)? Or maybe they have 1.6 "Donut" devices?

Comment: I deployed the app to a minimum SDK version of 8, so Donut devices can't run them. The error occures on ARMv6 devices, too.

Comment: Does the error occur **only** on ARMv6 devices? Or maybe you know some other property shared by many devices that have this error?

Comment: No, it doesn't only occur on ARMv6 devices. Maybe the error comes from cracked versions?

Comment: [Here is a report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076176/native-library-not-loading-under-android-4-0-3-miui-rom) about a similar problem. Maybe your problem, too, will be gone if you build both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` libraries?

Comment: Surely, google play will filter out MIPS devices if your app has armv7a binaries only?

Comment: Google Play filters out 1.6 devices, too. But it is still possible to "sideload" an APK and install it even if the device is known to be non-compatible.